# Spark GBTRegressor gives a RMSE that doesn't match the predictions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

This is what my already vectorized train and test datasets look like for mllib:

Train:

[image]

Test:

[image]

Both have been processed separately to avoid data leakage (Only missing values have been imputed). When I try to predict the results using Gradient Boosting, these are the results I get:

[image]

However, the evaluator shows results that do not match the error range shown in the predictions for the data range of both datasets. Specifically, the rmse that I obtain is 683.62. If I change the evaluator metric, for example to mse, I also get a value that does not match the prediction results.

```
#Dependencies
from pyspark.ml.regression import GBTRegressor
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
#Model
gbt = GBTRegressor(labelCol="label")
paramGrid = (ParamGridBuilder()\
  .addGrid(gbt.maxDepth, [3, 7])\
  .addGrid(gbt.maxIter, [10, 20])\
  .build())
# Evaluation metric
evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(metricName="rmse", labelCol=gbt.getLabelCol(), 
predictionCol=gbt.getPredictionCol())
# CrossValidator
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=gbt, 
                evaluator=evaluator, 
                estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid, 
                numFolds=3)
#Predictions
fitModel = cv.fit(train)
predictions = fitModel.transform(test)
rmse = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print(rmse)
```

Would anyone know why the evaluator does not match the displayed results at all?

Comment: Try to train your model in bigger train dataset, the data that u re is not enough

Comment: I didn't know that the size of the dataset could make RMSE meaningless. Anyway, train has about 30K observations (the maximum I can use locally before testing the model in the cloud), is that too few?
Thanks!